# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64 in java.library.path

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I'm having this error when I try to make a request with the WebClient in a spring application

I already added the netty dependency - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.53.Final

```
java.library.path, now trying export to -Dio.netty.native.workdir: /tmp
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1871)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1124)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:351)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:250)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:69)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:39)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopEpoll.<clinit>(DefaultLoopEpoll.java:47)
    at reactor.netty.resources.LoopResources.preferNative(LoopResources.java:233)
    at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultLoopResources.onClient(DefaultLoopResources.java:198)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources.onClient(TcpResources.java:219)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpTcpClient.connect(HttpClientConnect.java:136)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientOperator.connect(TcpClientOperator.java:43)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientOperator.connect(TcpClientOperator.java:43)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientOperator.connect(TcpClientOperator.java:43)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientOperator.connect(TcpClientOperator.java:43)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClientOperator.connect(TcpClientOperator.java:43)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient.connect(TcpClient.java:202)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientFinalizer.connect(HttpClientFinalizer.java:68)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientFinalizer.responseConnection(HttpClientFinalizer.java:85)
    at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector.connect(ReactorClientHttpConnector.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$0(DefaultWebClient.java:338)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4218)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1677)
    at br.com.bit55.service.SendSmsService.lambda$sendSms$2(SendSmsService.java:58)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
    at br.com.bit55.service.SendSmsService.sendSms(SendSmsService.java:35)
    at br.com.bit55.service.SendSmsServiceTest.sendSmsTest(SendSmsServiceTest.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
```

Can anyone tell me what could be wrong

The Code:

```
                WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://url.com") //I cant show the real url
                    .defaultHeader("subject", "Invoice Closing")
                    .build();

                Mono<ClassDTO> classDTOMono = webClient
                    .post()
                    .uri("/uri")
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(classDTO))
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(classDTO.class);

                classDTOMono.doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println("message:  " + throwable.getMessage())).block();
```

It gives this error when I call this line: classDTOMono.doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println("message:  " + throwable.getMessage())).block();

Comment: The Shared library is not where the jvm looks for it

Comment: Can you add the dependency configuration in maven for the project?